# grease pencil jagged lines

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

my Blender produces very jagged lines in 2D Animation mode (grease pencil). It seems to be updating my pens position at a very low framerate. Turning input samples to 10 has no effect. What do? Im ... [image]

Answer (score 1):

i think this will solve your problem. At the Draw menu go to :

- Options -> Check Post-processing menu
- Subbdivision Steps (1 -> 3)
- (Optional) Smooth (0.1 -> 2)

The quality of the stroke (number of points added which you can see in Edit mode) is inversly proportional to the drawing speed.
Sorry for my English, Hope it helps !

Comment: "The quality of the stroke (number of points added which you can see in Edit mode) is inversly proportional to the drawing speed" How do I change exactly that? because I cannot draw a proper circle even with post processing tuned. Is my Computer just too slow?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (now in 3.4), and I tried all those settings before realizing it's the "simplify" that binds it all. I lowered it and now I get the smoothness I want.